# Asymmetry when $t\rightarrow -t$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, reversibility, dissipation, time-reversal-symmetry

If we consider the equation of critical damping $$x=(a+bt)e^{-ct}$$
then the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vuhef0hx1i) is

[image]

However, it is asymmetric for positive and negative time values. I have an intuition that this should be the case but how to be more rigorous about it given that Newtonian mechanics is invariant for $t\rightarrow -t$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reversibility in classical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155138/)